# Saving an object on Parse

Tags: parse-platform, pfobject, before-save

On Parse.com when saving an object I implement Parse.Cloud.beforeSave.
But along the object to save I’d like to pass some extra information which is only for checking reasons and not part of the object to save.
How should I pass this kind of data?
Inside request.object and then remove it before saving? (I don’t know how to do that)
Any other solution? For example something like request.extraParameters that one could use.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave
(“MyClass”, function(request, response) {
request.object…..
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd go for a [cloud function](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started-simple):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveStuffWithExtraParameters", function(request, response) {
    //do something with extra parameters and save object here
});
```

You should have both your object and the extra parameters in the `request` object.

Comment: As for your approach, I am not entirely sure anymore it would work. THe issue is that you will need to remove those extra fields before saving the object. I don't have much experience with cloud code or JS, so this may or may not be straightforward. Best to check both options and see which works best :)

Comment: I ended up using your solution.
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave is not flexible enough to let me do what I wanted to.

Comment: Well I don't think there are any better workarounds. Cloud functions were probably made with this in mind.